# how to solve cannot send more than 16 receipts using php mailer?

Tags: phpmailer

**Code**

```
if ($redirectemail == "") 
{ 
    $mail->Body = $body; 
    $emailListArr = preg_split("/[;,]/", $toemail); 
    
    foreach ($emailListArr as $emailAdd) { 
        $mail->AddAddress(trim($emailAdd)); 
    }
}
```

**Error**

cannot send more than 16 receipts using php mailer

Comment: please provide more context to your question, proper error message and what have you tried or share you other findings.

Comment: PHPMailer does not impose any limit on the number of recipients (so your code tells us nothing) – but your email server might. What exactly happens when you have more than 16?